# Running a Batch Script through a Make File variable

Tags: batch-file, makefile

I have an executable that I am currently running through a batch script. But due to certain requirements, I need to be able to run the batch script through a makefile. My batch script for reference:

```
@echo off
start name.exe
```

I have tried the following:

```
run:
    @cmd /C "$(CURDIR)\name.bat"
```

Command used:
`make run`

This ran as expected and created a log file, so I tried to run the following:

```
    run:
        @cmd /C "@cmd /C "$(CURDIR)\name.bat"
    MOVE:=run
    .PHONY: all
    all: $(MOVE)
```

Command used:
 `make all`

The above ran just fine and generated the log file and moved some object files that were present to the appropriate locations, which is the desired output. When I tried to extend this logic to the main make file that I need to work with, of which below is a watered-down version:

```
run:    
    @cmd /C "$(CURDIR)/move.bat"  
FILE_LIST = BASE_SW  
MOVE:= run  
FILE_LIST:= BASE_SW (directory containing files)
LIB_FILE:= $(FILE_LIST).a  
$(LIB_FILE): $(MOVE) $(other dependency)    
         @mkdir-mingw -p $(dir name)         
         @$(AR) cr $(LIB_FILE_APP) $(ALL_OBJS_APP)  

.PHONY:all
all: $(LIB_FILE)
```

`make all`
When this is executed, it is all rosy till the Variable for the batch script is encountered at which point the batch script is not being run.
My main aim is to be able to run the batch script when the make file has a structure like below:

```
run:
    @cmd /C "$(CURDIR)/move.bat
MOVE:= run
LIB_FILE:= $(FILE).a
$(LIB_FILE): $(MOVE) $(Other dependencies)
          recipe
.PHONY: all
all: $(LIB_FILE)
```

Comment: Well, you haven't set the variable `MOVE` to anything in that makefile, so `$(MOVE)` expands to the empty string.  Did you just forget something in your example?

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. I have a large makefile within which variables just depend on other variables, and have a recipe associated with them I want to know if I could do something similar in the above case.

Comment: Sorry but you haven't actually asked a question, or answered my question.  If you don't set the variable `MOVE` to any value, then you say `all: $(MOVE)`, then `$(MOVE)` expands to the empty string and the `all` target doesn't depend on anything, so when you say `make all` make has nothing to do, and it tells you that.  You say you have a "large makefile" so clearly what you posted is not it: we can only help if you provide accurate information.  Please post a minimal, fully reproducible example and ask a clear question with examples of what happened and what you wanted to happen.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot provide the information on the large makefile. But my main intention is to run the batch script through a makefile variable that is being referenced by another makefile variable that is also utilised through reference. 
Something along the lines of LIB:=$(SWC_NAME).a, where LIB depends on MOVE,
$(LIB): $(MOVE), and $(LIB) has a recipe attached.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you provide your large makefile: we wouldn't want to read through it anyway.  I'm suggesting you create a complete, minimal example that shows the issue you have clearly, that you show how you invoke it, what output you get, and explain in detail why that result is not what you want and what results you do want.  I've already explained, twice, why the example you provided gives you "nothing to do" results.  If that's not answering your question you need to restate the question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I thank you for your patience and your time, I apologize for causing confusion. Explaination below:
```run:
 @cmd /C "$(CURDIR)/move.bat"

FILE_LIST = BASE_SW

MOVE:= run

LIB_FILE:= $(FILE_LIST).a

LIB_FILE: $(MOVE) $(other dependency)
 @mkdir-mingw -p $(dir name)
        @$(AR) cr $(LIB_FILE_APP) $(ALL_OBJS_APP)

.PHONY all:
all: $(LIB_FILE)
```
I am trying to move some object files into a folder using the batch script. Upon doing so the aim is to create a lib file. But when I implement the above, the batch script isn't being triggered to move the generated object files.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the updates there, as a code block.  It's impossible to review a makefile in comments where there is no formatting.  Also as in my comment, please show (cut and paste with formatting) the command you invoked and the output you got.  But at least here I can see you did set the `MOVE` variable to some value.

Comment: @MadScientist I have made some changes, please do take a look.

Comment: Include a small example (You did that), that has been run, and exhibits the problem (have you done that?).

Comment: @MadScientist, I was able to solve the issue. The main issue as you highlighted at the very beginning was the fact that MOVE wasn't set to any value. I just added the value, and was able to make the whole thing work! Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't shown (via cut and paste) the results you get.  I'll make a few points:

First, you should absolutely remove the `@` prefix on your recipes.  By adding these you are throwing away your most useful debugging output since make doesn't show you what it's doing.

Second, assuming you have a new-enough version of GNU Make you should use the `--trace` option to see what make is doing.

Third, note that by adding `$(LIB_FILE): $(MOVE) ...` you're saying that you want the `MOVE` target to run **before** the `LIB_FILE` target (prerequisites are always completely built before the target is built).  I don't know if that's what you want or not.

Comment: And `run` should be `.PHONY`. Else it won't get built if a file called `run` exists.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Essentially I wanted MOVE to run before the $(LIB_FILE), this was necessary to trigger a batch script that performs an action that is required as a dependency for another variable. So it is solved.